# Excel If Statement that returns multiple rows of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good day. I will start by providing the purpose for my request which should make it a little more understandable.

I am attempting to create a Meal Planner in Excel that allows the user to select a variety of meals from a drop down list. Once the meal is selected (and here is where I have trouble), I want the ingredients which are listed over multiple rows on another sheet to import into a desired column (ideally each  returned ingredient will still have it's own cell but this is not critical).

So it would be something like. If 'Hot Dog' from the list on A2 sheet 1 and then the ingredients: buns, hot dogs, ketchup, etc. from sheet 2 cells: x2t through x5 populate in A3 through A5 on sheet 1.

Using excel 2010.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a PIVOT TABLE. Your ingredients would be the row labels and the meal name would be the report filter which would give you your drop-down list above your ingredients.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your prompt response. I did not think about doing it in a pivot table. That could work. However, for formatting, and end user purposes, ideally I would be able to select the meal which would then list the ingredients on another sheet or column

Comment: Create a pivot table as I described, hide the top rows that show the drop-down. Go to your worksheet where you want users to select a meal, create a drop-down (form control or validation), create a macro that is triggered when the drop-down changes (form control event or worksheet change event) that updates the now hidden pivot table drop-down and refreshes the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand `from sheet 2 cells: x2t through x5` but assuming data such as shown in Sheet2 below, then

```
  =INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&CHAR(64+MATCH(A$2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$1,0))&ROW()-1)
```

in Sheet1 A3 and copied down to suit may be what you require.

Note that this would not work for more than 26 receipts.

A2 is the cell with validation (from Row1 of Sheet2).

[image]